# Can't login to an outlook web application using python crawler

Tags: python, authentication, web-crawler, session-cookies, outlook-web-app

Hi I am trying to login to an outlook web application using python web crawler but I am not getting through the login page. From what I noticed the site will redirect upon the get request and set a cookie; namely OutlookSession. Then the post request goes to the same url having this cookie and this is the reason I am using requests.Session().
This is my code:

```
import requests

URL = "https://mail.guc.edu.eg/owa"

username = "username"
password = "password"

s = requests.Session()
s.get(URL)
login_data={"username":username, "password":password}
r = s.post("https://mail.guc.edu.eg/owa", data=login_data)
```

Comment: you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: _Then the post request goes to the same url_ Are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on A Magoon's answer, there happens to be three additional form fields that OWA expects. This is what worked for me:

```
import requests

owa_login_form_url = 'https://mail.yourdomain.com/owa'

user_name = 'user'
pwd = 'pwd'
flags = '4'
forcedownlevel = '0'

sess = requests.Session()

payload = {'username': user_name, 'password': pwd, 'destination': owa_login_form_url, 'flags': flags, 'forcedownlevel': forcedownlevel }
resp = sess.post(owa_login_form_url + '/auth.owa', data=payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the form posts to `https://mail.guc.edu.eg/owa/auth.owa`.

```
import requests

URL = "https://mail.guc.edu.eg/owa"

username = "username"
password = "password"

s = requests.Session()
s.get(URL)
login_data={"username":username, "password":password}
r = s.post("https://mail.guc.edu.eg/owa/auth.owa", data=login_data)
```

Comment: Aha, my bad. However it still doesn't work after hanging the post url.  r.content from the post request prints the html of the login page .